# Syntax highlighting with GTK3 SourceView

Tags: python, gtk3, gtksourceview

How do you enable syntax highlighting in `GtkSourceView` using GTK3? My code below is not working.

```
# HTML view
self.scrolledwindow_html = builder.get_object('scrolledwindow_html')
self.sourceview_html = GtkSource.View()
self.buffer_html = self.sourceview_html.get_buffer()

lang_manager = GtkSource.LanguageManager()
self.buffer_html.set_language(lang_manager.get_language('html'))
self.scrolledwindow_html.add(self.sourceview_html)
```

Giving an error:

> AttributeError: 'TextBuffer' object has no attribute 'set_language'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the sourceview is initialising itself with a `Gtk.TextBuffer` (which doesn't know about syntax highlighting) instead of a `GtkSource.Buffer` (which does). Force it to use your choice of Buffer by making the buffer first, and telling `View` to use exactly that object:

```
 self.buffer_html = GtkSource.Buffer()
 self.sourceview_html = GtkSource.View.new_with_buffer(self.buffer_html)
```

Comment: You can monitor the status of this bug [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=643732).